# Ultimate Wordpress Query Search Filter AJAX Results Display

Tags: ajax, wordpress, search, plugins

I have the following code below. This code is used to display the results of a query. I have 2 pages that utilize this.

This should apply to page ID 6196:

```
get_template_part( 'includes/content', 'profile-loop' );
```

and this to page ID 12537:

```
get_template_part( 'includes/content', 'highlight-loop' );
```

I am looking for a method of swapping the `get_template_part` portion of the function depending on what page the visitor was on.

COMPLETE FUNCTION:

```
add_filter('uwpqsf_result_tempt', 'customize_output', '', 4);
function customize_output($results , $arg, $id, $getdata ){
 // The Query
        $apiclass = new uwpqsfprocess();
         $query = new WP_Query( $arg );
    ob_start(); $result = '';

    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            $query->the_post();global $post;
                    get_template_part( 'includes/content', 'profile-loop' );
            wp_reset_postdata();
            }
            }
    else {
        echo '<h3 class="center">No results. Try broadening your search parameters.</h3>';
        }

            $results = ob_get_clean();
            return $results;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use is_page() function and modify the loop as below:

```
while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
  $query->the_post();
  global $post;
  if( is_page( 6196 ) ){
  get_template_part( 'includes/content', 'profile-loop' );
}
elseif( is_page( 12537 ) ){
  get_template_part( 'includes/content', 'highlight-loop' );
}
  wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Comment: I think you can exclude global $post; as you are not using it anywhere.

Comment: Thanks, Ahmad. Unfortunately, it still isn't working as I had intended. It's actually not loading the template part now, which is odd. I will have to do some more investigating.